# Ubuntu and Windows 8 shared partition gets corrupted

Tags: windows-8, ntfs, multi-boot, ubuntu-12.04, filesystem-corruption

I have a dual boot (Ubuntu 12.04 and Windows 8) system. Both systems have access to an NTFS "DATA" partition which contains all my images, documents, music and some application data like Chrome and Thunderbird Profiles which used by both OS.

Everything was working fine in my Dual boot Ubuntu/Windows 7, but after updating to Windows 8 I am having a lot of troubles. First, sometimes, I add some files from Ubuntu into my DATA partition but they don't show up in Windows. Sometimes, I can't even use the DATA partition from Windows. When I try to save a file it gives an error "The directory or file is corrupted or unreadable". I need to run checkdisk to fix it but after some time, same error appears.

Before upgrading to Windows 8 I also installed a new hard drive and copied the old data using clonezilla (full disk clone).

Here is the log of my last chkdisk:

```
Chkdsk was executed in read/write mode.  

Checking file system on D:
Volume dismounted.  All opened handles to this volume are now invalid.
Volume label is DATA.

CHKDSK is verifying files (stage 1 of 3)...
Deleted corrupt attribute list entry
with type code 128 in file 67963.
Unable to find child frs 0x12a3f with sequence number 0x15.
The attribute of type 0x80 and instance tag 0x2 in file 0x1097b
has allocated length of 0x560000 instead of 0x427000.
Deleted corrupt attribute list entry
with type code 128 in file 67963.
Unable to locate attribute with instance tag 0x2 and segment
reference 0x1e00000001097b.  The expected attribute type is 0x80.
Deleting corrupt attribute record (128, "")
from file record segment 67963.
Attribute record of type 0x80 and instance tag 0x3 is cross linked
starting at 0x2431b2 for possibly 0x20 clusters.
Some clusters occupied by attribute of type 0x80 and instance tag 0x3
in file 0x1791e is already in use.
Deleting corrupt attribute record (128, "")
from file record segment 96542.
Attribute record of type 0x80 and instance tag 0x4 is cross linked
starting at 0x6bc7 for possibly 0x1 clusters.
Some clusters occupied by attribute of type 0x80 and instance tag 0x4
in file 0x17e83 is already in use.
Deleting corrupt attribute record (128, "")
from file record segment 97923.
Attribute record of type 0x80 and instance tag 0x4 is cross linked
starting at 0x1f7cec for possibly 0x5 clusters.
Some clusters occupied by attribute of type 0x80 and instance tag 0x4
in file 0x17eaf is already in use.
Deleting corrupt attribute record (128, "")
from file record segment 97967.
Attribute record of type 0x80 and instance tag 0x2 is cross linked
starting at 0x441bd7f for possibly 0x9 clusters.
Some clusters occupied by attribute of type 0x80 and instance tag 0x2
in file 0x32085 is already in use.
Deleting corrupt attribute record (128, "")
from file record segment 204933.
Attribute record of type 0x80 and instance tag 0x2 is cross linked
starting at 0x4457850 for possibly 0x1 clusters.
Some clusters occupied by attribute of type 0x80 and instance tag 0x2
in file 0x320be is already in use.
Deleting corrupt attribute record (128, "")
from file record segment 204990.
Attribute record of type 0x80 and instance tag 0x2 is cross linked
starting at 0x4859249 for possibly 0x1 clusters.
Some clusters occupied by attribute of type 0x80 and instance tag 0x2
in file 0x3726b is already in use.
Deleting corrupt attribute record (128, "")
from file record segment 225899.
Attribute record of type 0x80 and instance tag 0x2 is cross linked
starting at 0x485d309 for possibly 0x1 clusters.
Some clusters occupied by attribute of type 0x80 and instance tag 0x2
in file 0x3726c is already in use.
Deleting corrupt attribute record (128, "")
from file record segment 225900.
Attribute record of type 0x80 and instance tag 0x2 is cross linked
starting at 0x48a47de for possibly 0x1 clusters.
Some clusters occupied by attribute of type 0x80 and instance tag 0x2
in file 0x37286 is already in use.
Deleting corrupt attribute record (128, "")
from file record segment 225926.
Attribute record of type 0x80 and instance tag 0x2 is cross linked
starting at 0x48ac80b for possibly 0x1 clusters.
Some clusters occupied by attribute of type 0x80 and instance tag 0x2
in file 0x37287 is already in use.
Deleting corrupt attribute record (128, "")
from file record segment 225927.
Attribute record of type 0x80 and instance tag 0x2 is cross linked
starting at 0x48ae7ef for possibly 0x1 clusters.
Some clusters occupied by attribute of type 0x80 and instance tag 0x2
in file 0x37288 is already in use.
Deleting corrupt attribute record (128, "")
from file record segment 225928.
Attribute record of type 0x80 and instance tag 0x2 is cross linked
starting at 0x48af7f8 for possibly 0x1 clusters.
Some clusters occupied by attribute of type 0x80 and instance tag 0x2
in file 0x3728a is already in use.
Deleting corrupt attribute record (128, "")
from file record segment 225930.
Attribute record of type 0x80 and instance tag 0x2 is cross linked
starting at 0x48c39b6 for possibly 0x1 clusters.
Some clusters occupied by attribute of type 0x80 and instance tag 0x2
in file 0x37292 is already in use.
Deleting corrupt attribute record (128, "")
from file record segment 225938.
Attribute record of type 0x80 and instance tag 0x2 is cross linked
starting at 0x495d37a for possibly 0x1 clusters.
Some clusters occupied by attribute of type 0x80 and instance tag 0x2
in file 0x372d7 is already in use.
Deleting corrupt attribute record (128, "")
from file record segment 226007.
Attribute record of type 0xa0 and instance tag 0x5 is cross linked
starting at 0x4d0bd38 for possibly 0x1 clusters.
Some clusters occupied by attribute of type 0xa0 and instance tag 0x5
in file 0x372dc is already in use.
Deleting corrupt attribute record (160, $I30)
from file record segment 226012.
Attribute record of type 0xa0 and instance tag 0x5 is cross linked
starting at 0x4c2d9bc for possibly 0x1 clusters.
Some clusters occupied by attribute of type 0xa0 and instance tag 0x5
in file 0x372ed is already in use.
Deleting corrupt attribute record (160, $I30)
from file record segment 226029.
Attribute record of type 0x80 and instance tag 0x2 is cross linked
starting at 0x4a4c1c3 for possibly 0x1 clusters.
Some clusters occupied by attribute of type 0x80 and instance tag 0x2
in file 0x37354 is already in use.
Deleting corrupt attribute record (128, "")
from file record segment 226132.
Attribute record of type 0x80 and instance tag 0x2 is cross linked
starting at 0x4a8e639 for possibly 0x1 clusters.
Some clusters occupied by attribute of type 0x80 and instance tag 0x2
in file 0x37376 is already in use.
Deleting corrupt attribute record (128, "")
from file record segment 226166.
Attribute record of type 0x80 and instance tag 0x2 is cross linked
starting at 0x4a8f6eb for possibly 0x1 clusters.
Some clusters occupied by attribute of type 0x80 and instance tag 0x2
in file 0x37379 is already in use.
Deleting corrupt attribute record (128, "")
from file record segment 226169.
Attribute record of type 0x80 and instance tag 0x2 is cross linked
starting at 0x4ae1aa8 for possibly 0x1 clusters.
Some clusters occupied by attribute of type 0x80 and instance tag 0x2
in file 0x37391 is already in use.
Deleting corrupt attribute record (128, "")
from file record segment 226193.
Attribute record of type 0xa0 and instance tag 0x5 is cross linked
starting at 0x4b00d45 for possibly 0x1 clusters.
Some clusters occupied by attribute of type 0xa0 and instance tag 0x5
in file 0x37396 is already in use.
Deleting corrupt attribute record (160, $I30)
from file record segment 226198.
Attribute record of type 0x80 and instance tag 0x2 is cross linked
starting at 0x4b02d50 for possibly 0x1 clusters.
Some clusters occupied by attribute of type 0x80 and instance tag 0x2
in file 0x3739c is already in use.
Deleting corrupt attribute record (128, "")
from file record segment 226204.
Attribute record of type 0x80 and instance tag 0x2 is cross linked
starting at 0x4b3407a for possibly 0x1 clusters.
Some clusters occupied by attribute of type 0x80 and instance tag 0x2
in file 0x373a8 is already in use.
Deleting corrupt attribute record (128, "")
from file record segment 226216.
Attribute record of type 0x80 and instance tag 0x2 is cross linked
starting at 0x4bd8a1b for possibly 0x1 clusters.
Some clusters occupied by attribute of type 0x80 and instance tag 0x2
in file 0x373db is already in use.
Deleting corrupt attribute record (128, "")
from file record segment 226267.
Attribute record of type 0x80 and instance tag 0x2 is cross linked
starting at 0x4bd9a28 for possibly 0x1 clusters.
Some clusters occupied by attribute of type 0x80 and instance tag 0x2
in file 0x373dd is already in use.
Deleting corrupt attribute record (128, "")
from file record segment 226269.
Attribute record of type 0x80 and instance tag 0x2 is cross linked
starting at 0x4c2fb24 for possibly 0x1 clusters.
Some clusters occupied by attribute of type 0x80 and instance tag 0x2
in file 0x373f3 is already in use.
Deleting corrupt attribute record (128, "")
from file record segment 226291.
Attribute record of type 0x80 and instance tag 0x2 is cross linked
starting at 0x4cb67e9 for possibly 0x1 clusters.
Some clusters occupied by attribute of type 0x80 and instance tag 0x2
in file 0x37424 is already in use.
Deleting corrupt attribute record (128, "")
from file record segment 226340.
Attribute record of type 0x80 and instance tag 0x2 is cross linked
starting at 0x4cba829 for possibly 0x2 clusters.
Some clusters occupied by attribute of type 0x80 and instance tag 0x2
in file 0x37425 is already in use.
Deleting corrupt attribute record (128, "")
from file record segment 226341.
Attribute record of type 0x80 and instance tag 0x2 is cross linked
starting at 0x4cbe868 for possibly 0x1 clusters.
Some clusters occupied by attribute of type 0x80 and instance tag 0x2
in file 0x37427 is already in use.
Deleting corrupt attribute record (128, "")
from file record segment 226343.
Attribute record of type 0x80 and instance tag 0x2 is cross linked
starting at 0x4cbf878 for possibly 0x1 clusters.
Some clusters occupied by attribute of type 0x80 and instance tag 0x2
in file 0x37428 is already in use.
Deleting corrupt attribute record (128, "")
from file record segment 226344.
Attribute record of type 0x80 and instance tag 0x2 is cross linked
starting at 0x4cc58d8 for possibly 0x1 clusters.
Some clusters occupied by attribute of type 0x80 and instance tag 0x2
in file 0x3742a is already in use.
Deleting corrupt attribute record (128, "")
from file record segment 226346.
Attribute record of type 0x80 and instance tag 0x2 is cross linked
starting at 0x4ccc943 for possibly 0x1 clusters.
Some clusters occupied by attribute of type 0x80 and instance tag 0x2
in file 0x3742b is already in use.
Deleting corrupt attribute record (128, "")
from file record segment 226347.
Attribute record of type 0x80 and instance tag 0x2 is cross linked
starting at 0x4cd199b for possibly 0x1 clusters.
Some clusters occupied by attribute of type 0x80 and instance tag 0x2
in file 0x3742d is already in use.
Deleting corrupt attribute record (128, "")
from file record segment 226349.
Attribute record of type 0x80 and instance tag 0x2 is cross linked
starting at 0x4cd29a8 for possibly 0x1 clusters.
Some clusters occupied by attribute of type 0x80 and instance tag 0x2
in file 0x3742f is already in use.
Deleting corrupt attribute record (128, "")
from file record segment 226351.
Attribute record of type 0x80 and instance tag 0x2 is cross linked
starting at 0x4cd39b8 for possibly 0x2 clusters.
Some clusters occupied by attribute of type 0x80 and instance tag 0x2
in file 0x37430 is already in use.
Deleting corrupt attribute record (128, "")
from file record segment 226352.
Attribute record of type 0x80 and instance tag 0x2 is cross linked
starting at 0x4cd49c8 for possibly 0x2 clusters.
Some clusters occupied by attribute of type 0x80 and instance tag 0x2
in file 0x37432 is already in use.
Deleting corrupt attribute record (128, "")
from file record segment 226354.
Attribute record of type 0x80 and instance tag 0x2 is cross linked
starting at 0x4cd9a16 for possibly 0x1 clusters.
Some clusters occupied by attribute of type 0x80 and instance tag 0x2
in file 0x37435 is already in use.
Deleting corrupt attribute record (128, "")
from file record segment 226357.
Attribute record of type 0x80 and instance tag 0x2 is cross linked
starting at 0x4cdca46 for possibly 0x1 clusters.
Some clusters occupied by attribute of type 0x80 and instance tag 0x2
in file 0x37436 is already in use.
Deleting corrupt attribute record (128, "")
from file record segment 226358.
Attribute record of type 0x80 and instance tag 0x2 is cross linked
starting at 0x4ce0a78 for possibly 0x1 clusters.
Some clusters occupied by attribute of type 0x80 and instance tag 0x2
in file 0x37437 is already in use.
Deleting corrupt attribute record (128, "")
from file record segment 226359.
Attribute record of type 0x80 and instance tag 0x2 is cross linked
starting at 0x4ce6ad9 for possibly 0x1 clusters.
Some clusters occupied by attribute of type 0x80 and instance tag 0x2
in file 0x3743a is already in use.
Deleting corrupt attribute record (128, "")
from file record segment 226362.
Attribute record of type 0x80 and instance tag 0x2 is cross linked
starting at 0x4cebb28 for possibly 0x1 clusters.
Some clusters occupied by attribute of type 0x80 and instance tag 0x2
in file 0x3743b is already in use.
Deleting corrupt attribute record (128, "")
from file record segment 226363.
Attribute record of type 0x80 and instance tag 0x2 is cross linked
starting at 0x4ceeb67 for possibly 0x1 clusters.
Some clusters occupied by attribute of type 0x80 and instance tag 0x2
in file 0x3743d is already in use.
Deleting corrupt attribute record (128, "")
from file record segment 226365.
Attribute record of type 0x80 and instance tag 0x2 is cross linked
starting at 0x4cf4bc6 for possibly 0x1 clusters.
Some clusters occupied by attribute of type 0x80 and instance tag 0x2
in file 0x3743e is already in use.
Deleting corrupt attribute record (128, "")
from file record segment 226366.
Attribute record of type 0x80 and instance tag 0x2 is cross linked
starting at 0x4cfbc3a for possibly 0x1 clusters.
Some clusters occupied by attribute of type 0x80 and instance tag 0x2
in file 0x37440 is already in use.
Deleting corrupt attribute record (128, "")
from file record segment 226368.
Attribute record of type 0x80 and instance tag 0x2 is cross linked
starting at 0x4cfcc48 for possibly 0x1 clusters.
Some clusters occupied by attribute of type 0x80 and instance tag 0x2
in file 0x37442 is already in use.
Deleting corrupt attribute record (128, "")
from file record segment 226370.
Attribute record of type 0x80 and instance tag 0x2 is cross linked
starting at 0x4d02ca9 for possibly 0x1 clusters.
Some clusters occupied by attribute of type 0x80 and instance tag 0x2
in file 0x37443 is already in use.
Deleting corrupt attribute record (128, "")
from file record segment 226371.
Attribute record of type 0x80 and instance tag 0x2 is cross linked
starting at 0x4d06ce8 for possibly 0x1 clusters.
Some clusters occupied by attribute of type 0x80 and instance tag 0x2
in file 0x37444 is already in use.
Deleting corrupt attribute record (128, "")
from file record segment 226372.
Attribute record of type 0xa0 and instance tag 0x5 is cross linked
starting at 0x4d9a608 for possibly 0x2 clusters.
Some clusters occupied by attribute of type 0xa0 and instance tag 0x5
in file 0x37449 is already in use.
Deleting corrupt attribute record (160, $I30)
from file record segment 226377.
Attribute record of type 0xa0 and instance tag 0x5 is cross linked
starting at 0x4d844ab for possibly 0x1 clusters.
Some clusters occupied by attribute of type 0xa0 and instance tag 0x5
in file 0x3744b is already in use.
Deleting corrupt attribute record (160, $I30)
from file record segment 226379.
Attribute record of type 0xa0 and instance tag 0x5 is cross linked
starting at 0x4d6c32b for possibly 0x1 clusters.
Some clusters occupied by attribute of type 0xa0 and instance tag 0x5
in file 0x3744c is already in use.
Deleting corrupt attribute record (160, $I30)
from file record segment 226380.
Attribute record of type 0xa0 and instance tag 0x5 is cross linked
starting at 0x4d2af25 for possibly 0x1 clusters.
Some clusters occupied by attribute of type 0xa0 and instance tag 0x5
in file 0x3744e is already in use.
Deleting corrupt attribute record (160, $I30)
from file record segment 226382.
Attribute record of type 0x80 and instance tag 0x2 is cross linked
starting at 0x4d0fd78 for possibly 0x1 clusters.
Some clusters occupied by attribute of type 0x80 and instance tag 0x2
in file 0x37451 is already in use.
Deleting corrupt attribute record (128, "")
from file record segment 226385.
Attribute record of type 0x80 and instance tag 0x2 is cross linked
starting at 0x4d16ef8 for possibly 0x1 clusters.
Some clusters occupied by attribute of type 0x8
```

Can anyone help?
Thank you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

By default, Windows 8 doesn't cleanly unmount filesystems on shutdown, it seems.  I've seen this mentioned elsewhere on StackOverflow.  (W.r.t to the UEFI boot partition!)  They gave a command-line method to disable it, but this GUI method is almost certainly the same thing:

http://www.askvg.com/fix-windows-8-restart-and-shutdown-problems-by-disabling-hybrid-shutdown-feature/

I'm surprised this would apply to separate data filesystems, but it does seem worth looking at.

Comment: interesting. This makes some sense and might explain some troubles I also have with shared profiles of chrome, thunderbird etc. I am running a chkdisk and a defrag right now and I have disabled that option. Hope it works.

Answer (score 2):

It's probably because your win8 has the "fast startup" enabled. So, when you turn your windows off, it saves the information about the state of mounted partitions to reduce time for the next boot. So when you copy or change a file with ubuntu, windows will not recognize it because of its previous saved state for the partition.

The solution seems to be disabling win8's fast startup feature.
Here are the instructions for that.
http://itsfoss.com/solve-ntfs-mount-problem-ubuntu-windows-8-dual-boot/